# The union of two closed sets is a closed set and the intersect of a family of closed sets is a closed set.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F$ be an algebraically closed field, $I ⊂ F [X_1, X_2, . . . , X_n]$ an ideal. Denote by $S(I)$ the subset in $F^n$ consisting of all $n-$tuples $(a_1, a_2, . . . , a_n) ∈ F^n$ such that $f(a_1,a_2,...,a_n) = 0$ for all $f ∈ I$. A subset $S ⊂ F^n$ is called closed if $S = S(I)$ for some ideal $I ⊂ F[X_1,X_2,...,X_n]$. Prove that the union of two closed subsets and the intersection of any family of closed subsets is also closed.

I tried to prove $S(I_1)\cup S(I_2)=S(I_1I_2)$, but I need to assume that $F^n$ is a field. $F^n$ is not a field because it has zero divisors. So I don't know how to do that. For intersection, I think the intersection is equal to $S($$\sum I_j)$, but I didn't use the assumption that $F$ is algebraically  closed. So I want to know how other people do that.

Comment: What have you tried so far? (_Show_ your work by editing the main question itself, don't just describe it in a few words or in the comments.) At what point (and why) did you get stuck?

Comment: Why do you need to assume $F^n$ is a field?

Comment: I don't know... I got confused. But I really didn't use the assumption that $F$ is algebraically closed. How do you do that problem? Did you use that assumption?

Comment: Since you have a solution, why don't you post it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X = S(I_1)$, $Y= S(I_2)$.

Clearly, $X \cup Y \subseteq S(I_1 I_2)$. Take a point $P \in S(I_1 I_2)$. Suppose $P \notin Y$, i.e. there is a polynomial $g \in I_2$ such that $g(P) \ne 0$. But by definition, for any polynomial $f \in I_1$, $fg \in I_1 I_2$ so $fg (P) = 0$ so $f(P) = 0$.

Comment: So I don't need the assumption that $F$ is algebraically closed for both union and intersection?

Comment: No, algebraic geometry is applied frequently to algebraic number theory and other areas where the base field is not closed. A common application is elliptic curves over finite fields.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use double inclusion.

Take $x \in  \cap S(I_\alpha)$. Then $f(x) = 0, \forall f \in I_\alpha$ and $ \forall \alpha$. This implies $x \in S(\sum I_\alpha)$.

For the other inclusion use that $I_\alpha \subset \sum I_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$ and that $S$ inverts inclusion.

You'll probably need algebraically closed to proved Hilbert's nullstellensatz later in the course. (assumig you're studing algebraic curves or something related to that)